# Start pi_video_looper from Python

Tags: python, video

I am new to Python so please be kind ;) I am trying to start the [Adafruit Video Looper](https://github.com/adafruit/pi_video_looper) from a python script.

Basically I have this code:

```
from pi_video_looper.Adafruit_Video_Looper.video_looper import VideoLooper

looper = VideoLooper(os.path.abspath("video_looper.ini"))
```

But it throws this error:

```
File "/home/pi/pi_video_looper/Adafruit_Video_Looper/video_looper.py",  line 70, in __init__
pygame.display.init()
pygame.error: Unable to open a console terminal
```

What can I do?

Comment: I would comment if i could by i don't have enough reputation. Have you tried running your python script with sudo? My first guess would be permissions issuse, which may be solved with sudo. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you running this within the Raspbian Desktop ?

Comment: I run that from an SSH session…

Comment: @LecauseAndThePi Your Guess seams to be right… Works if I run that as root, if you answer i will accept

Answer (score 0):

I would comment if i could by i don't have enough reputation. Have you tried running your python script with sudo? My first guess would be permissions issuse, which may be solved with sudo. Hope this helps.